# Xamarin.Forms IOS Wont build

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am getting the following error in Visual Studio:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error 2016-11-10 08:12:21.588 ibtoold[1725:9661] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-11542/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager.m:254
>   Details: Failed to attach to Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool with error: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8f53b7e450 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "Invalid argument" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8f53c086a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "Invalid argument"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to spawn Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool on SimDevice : IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (4F7AF09B-A326-4A75-8657-3269C0EF6AE9) : state={ Shutdown } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x } runtime={ SimRuntime : 10.1 (14B72) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-1 }, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool via CoreSimulator spawn}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (-1) failed to launch}
>   Object: 
>   Method: +_THREADSAFE_launchNewToolWithLaunchContext:executionContext:toolProxyClass:failureContext:requestingMethod:error:forReason:
>   Thread: {number = 1, name = main}
>   Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
>   2016-11-10 08:12:21.588 ibtoold[1725:9661] [MT] IBPlatformTool: *** Failed to launch tool with description System content 2x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-NineOneAndLater w/ default fidelity: Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. (Failure reason: Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (-1) failed to launch): Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool via CoreSimulator spawn (Failure reason: Failed to spawn Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool on SimDevice : IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (4F7AF09B-A326-4A75-8657-3269C0EF6AE9) : state={ Shutdown } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x } runtime={ SimRuntime : 10.1 (14B72) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-1 }): The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument (Failure reason: Invalid argument)
>   2016-11-10 08:12:35.502 ibtoold[1725:9661] [MT] IBPlatformTool: Wrote failed marshalling request diagnostics to path: /var/folders/tn/0v0_c5j95614q6vh8_blgjqc0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-11-10_08-12-29_853000 InspectMobile.iOS

and also

> Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/tn/0v0_c5j95614q6vh8_blgjqc0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-11-10_10-13-47_446000".

Sometimes this error doesn't happen but 99.99% of the time it does
I have the following installed :

on my windows pc

- Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.719

on my Mac

- Xcode 8.1
- xamarin.ios-10.2.0.4 installed

I am trying to build to a emulator but I have also tried to build to a device, same error occures.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Not really, but after I installed Xcode on my mac mini everything worked, but on my mac I get this errors

Comment: This one is already killing me. I'll post update if I resolve.